# Scrollbar с множеством кнопок tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, scrollbar

как создать окно с большим списком кнопок и возможностью его пролистывать ?

одна из попыток реализации ни к чему не привела ...

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("400x200")



frame = Frame(borderwidth=1, relief=SOLID)
scroll = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=frame.yview)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
for i in range(33):
    button = Button(frame, text=i, width=10)
    button.pack(fill=X)

frame.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
frame["yscrollcommand"]=scroll.set


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Только виджеты List, Textbox, Canvas и Entry поддерживают интерфейс полосы прокрутки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter